# rails rspec stubbed ActiveRecord::Relation for ActiveRecord Serialize

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, rspec, rails-activerecord, rspec-rails

can I stub ActiveRecord::Relation for ActiveRecord Serialize !?

I could stub ActiveRecord::Relation .. but it doesn't work for ActiveRecord Serialize !

In my controller, I have sth like this:

```
@res = ModelName.includes(...).where(...).order(..).page(..).per(..)
render json: {
   res: ActiveModelSerializers::SerializableResource.new(
      res,
      each_serializer: ModelNameSerializer,
      meta: pagination_dict(@res)
      adapter: :json
   ).as_json
 }
```

In rspec test file, I did sth like this:

```
relation = ModelName.all.page(1)
allow(relation).to receive(:[]).and_return([obj_1, obj_2])
allow(ModelName).to receive_message_chain(:includes, :where, :order, :page, :per).and_return(
      relation
    )
```

there's no error, but still Serialize return 0 object!, so stub operator `[]` doesn't work for `each_serializer` !

any idea ?!, thanks

Comment: Don't stub it in the first place? Instead arrange the spec to create the database records. Stubbing out the db in request/controller specs is rarely a good idea since a large part of what controllers do is integrate with the DB.

Comment: you also don't need to manually create `ActiveModelSerializers::SerializableResource`. Just use `render json: @res, each_serializer: ModelNameSerializer, meta: pagination_dict(@res)`.

Your also declaring the instance variable `@res` and using a local variable `res`.

Comment: @max thanks, actually I'm using mutation ruby gem .. so the integrate with the DB is not in controller level, that's why I don't write integration test for controller ... and I'm trying to stub records in rspec .. to improve the running test speed ...